# 3D rendering on a budget; What to upgrade?

Tags: rendering, 3d

I just built a PC for my wife; i3-4130 / B85 / 8GB RAM / Radeon 7730 1GB GDDR5 / 120GB Intel 330 SSD / 22" HP IPS Monitor.

She's an interior designer and she uses this software, 20-20 Design. She's satisfied with its performance over her Samsung laptop with i5-2430M with integrated graphics (the new desktop renders significantly quicker and has a lot better image quality), although even quicker render times will always be nice. Of course I am on a budget.

My questions are:

1. Would it be better if I instead purchased a cheaper but 2GB video card? Perhaps a Radeon 7730 2GB DDR3?
2. If she wanted to render quicker for a similar price, would it be better if I purchased an AMD processor with more cores? Or will the Intel Haswell still do a better job with its 2 cores?
3. Is it the Haswell i3-4130 that renders much faster than the Sandy Bridge i5-2430m? They're both dual-cores (although 3.4Ghz vs 2.4Ghz), or does the video card also help in rendering times?

Comment: You won't be able to go from an Intel CPU to AMD CPU unless you replace the motherboard which means spending more money overall. You have a low end Haswell CPU you should verify the current mothoerboard can support a i5 i7 before you make any choices. What would help with rendering entirely depends on what the program uses either the GPU or CPU contact the company who made the program that question.  The performance differences between an AMD CPU vs CPU CPU in the real word performance almost don't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the [System Requirements](http://www.2020technologies.com/home/interior-design/kitchen-bath-and-home-organization/2020-design#&panel1-1), I would say that if you want it faster, I'd go for a CPU upgrade.

However, an easy way to see if it's the CPU or GPU holding you back, you could have a peek in the task manager to see whether the CPU is maxing out when a render is being done. If it's maxing out, then upgrading the CPU will help. If it's not, then the GPU is what's holding the speed back.

---

In response to your questions

> Would it be better if I instead purchased a cheaper but 2GB video card? Perhaps a Radeon 7730 2GB DDR3?

In this case, they're much the sameness. The amount of RAM is important to your needs, not the speed.

> If she wanted to render quicker for a similar price, would it be better if I purchased an AMD processor with more cores? Or will the Intel Haswell still do a better job with its 2 cores?

That would be hard to say. It would depend on how the application is designed. Generally however, Intel CPUs perform better than AMD CPUs.

> Is it the Haswell i3-4130 that renders much faster than the Sandy Bridge i5-2430m? They're both dual-cores (although 3.4Ghz vs 2.4Ghz), or does the video card also help in rendering times?

I'd say it's the graphics card that helps it render faster. But that's just an educated guess. The graphics card can do a lot of the heavy lifting when it comes to rendering 3D scenes. Lighting, reflections, transparency etc would likely be done by the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I almost commented on Lawrence's answer, but reconsidered as my thoughts stand as an answer on their own.

I've been down this journey a few times via various paths... and I'm still not exactly satisfied with the results. *Now, on to the arms race of "graphics" performance:*

**CPU**
Start with Lawrence's advice on checking the CPU in performance monitor. Most programs are sadly single threaded. If this is the case, then more cores just empties your wallet. I use Rhinoceros 3D for CAD and it is almost always single threaded (only uses 1 core).

When your app is single threaded and can't use more cores, you need the newest architecture you can afford, the fastest clock speed possible, but with the least cores available. That means get a Core i3 with 3GHz+ clock speed. Mentioning Core i3 may not be the most current advice: google site:overclock.net about CPU performance. And Intel all the way. IMHO, AMD is great for servers (I have a 1055t in mine) but Intel for desktops.

Caveat: when you're maxing out that program and only have 2 cores, make sure THAT is the only program running. You can alt-tab over to your Firefox with 30 tabs open and play candy crush.

My Experience: I've gone from dual core to core 2 duo to 6 core to xeon 4 core (dual thread), all of them overclocked. I like to punish the program than switch to something else and stay productive while my task has the CAD program go all white.

**RAM**
I consider 4G to be insufficient for anything more than having a browser and one or two office programs open. Check out the performance monitor, you'll see. The problem is, you need to pay attention to the Windows OS version and its RAM limits. Right off, you need to be on 64 bit version of the OS. You can get 8GB in Win7 Home Basic. That's a great first step. ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)) Sadly, Home Premium limits you to 16G, so anything at work that does more than office-y stuff has to run Win 7 64 Pro. Speed or version of RAM is almost irrelevant imho. You're not overclocking or benchmarking. If 2G or 4G is holding you back, the cheapest 8G is going to feel like a Ferrari.

**GPU**
This is the tough one. Once the above two are assuredly not holding you back, this is the last continent to explore. If I hadn't personally seen what a Quadro workstation card can do, I would not be a believer in graphics cards.

I had a pretty good on-board HDMI output on my CAD box of the moment and was taking my computer back and forth with me to work. I had spare peripherals at home and work, so it was only the box. At work I was using a 24" DVI monitor and at home is a higher end 42" Sony HDTV. I was given (*as in for free, like free beer*) a Quadro FX3800. It was waaay more than I needed, but a customer saw me talk about my problems and gave me a factory hook-up. I'm in the 2nd or 3rd week working on my CAD project at home and I see something... off the corner of my model... zoom zoom zoom zoom oh wow, there's trash hanging out there I didn't notice before! Those last two zooms were impossible to "see" before the new card.

*But*, I didn't talk about rendering per-se, zooming in and re-drawing is a cousin to rendering, so we could be talking about the same thing or semantics has us in separate topics when it comes to GPU performance. You need to talk to technical support at the manufacturer of the software you're using and find out exactly what video hardware they have observed in their own lab to appear to be the best performance at realistic pricing. From my experience, they'll do their best to help because then you'll like them more and keep on buying their products.

**GUI**
When doing CAD-like stuff, see if the [3D Connexion Space Navigator](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacenavigator.html) works in your software! OMG, I love it so much I bought a 2nd one to sit at home for the few times I do CAD at home on my laptop. It is like flying a helicopter through your drawing; you can get the view exactly on what you're doing! I have found so many minuscule defects where edges don't meet up properly via this + a good GPU.

**My System**
OK, so I gave all this advice. Here's [my CAD computer](http://www.overclock.net/lists/display/view/id/5217451/version/5217453). What's sad is that I humbly say "yeah it's ok", when it's a stonkin epic computer. The only thing(s) I bought new for it were the RAM and the AMD GPU. The rest was legacy stuff from other computers.

The core i7 was from a Gateway store-box computer. It was the only thing worth beans in that whole computer. I bought a core i3 for it and it's a spare workstation for guests now. The Motherboard had only 2 slots and I recall was limited to 4G of RAM. :P I ganked it's CPU when I saw a core i3 on OCN for sale, which I put in my CAD box.

The AMD GPU was on a special sale where they gave me a gift card for buying it. The only reason I bought it was when I moved my Quadro to the latest build, it stopped working. Got me why. I researched and the W5000 was the best performance for the money at the moment.

RAM? 16G was enough for a long while. Then I got the laser scanner which upped the ante a LOT for filesize. :P There are 4 slots in the motherboard with 4 4GB sticks. So I went to 4 8GB sticks. If you buy memory, buy 8GB sticks so you only need to buy TWO to upgrade from 16G to 32G!!

*Next time** I'm buying a server-type motherboard that can have even more RAM. The more ram you've got, the less programs need to "think" it seems. Get enough and you can make a RAM disk and save your files there, too. Win7Pro goes up to 192G; that's bigger than my SSD! After that, I'd get whatever processor has the highest "boost" speed and not care about cores. 4 or more are all the same unless you're certain your tasks are using those extra cores.